# Emacs/Spacemacs — rebind SLIME `eval-last-expression-in-repl` (, s e) to ctrl-enter

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime, spacemacs

I’m using `emacs` / `spacemacs`.

I see that:

```
, s e      # slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl
```

sends the current highlighted line to the repl and runs it, exactly what I want.

How to add a binding into emacs/spacemacs to do the same but using `ctrl-enter` / `ctrl-RET` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following lines in your [`~/.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) file:

```
(eval-after-load 'slime-repl 
  (define-key slime-repl-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>")
              'slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl))
```

If you have trouble getting this to work in terminal emacs (`emacs -nw`), check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536352/ctrl-enter-shift-enter-and-enter-are-interpreted-as-the-same-key) related question.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For `spacemacs`, i had to change `eval-after-load` to `with-eval-after-load`, and the mode map to `lisp-mode-map` to get the shortcut working from lisp code buffer.

Comment: I also had to use `with-eval-after-load`, and I'm using ordinary emacs on debian